# \newdimen in LaTeX is 0pt after assignment, why?

Tags: tables, subfloats, dimensions

In the below example, I print out the two dimens in the subfigure captions. Surprisingly (to me), the first one prints correctly but the second one is somehow zero pts.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\frame{\frametitle{testing}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{cc}

\newdimen\fluxfigwidth
\fluxfigwidth=0.5\textwidth
\newdimen\fluxlegwidth
\fluxlegwidth=\textwidth
% I want to do this eventually:
% \advance\fluxlegwidth-\fluxfigwidth
% \begin{subfigure}[lb]{\fluxfigwidth\textwidth}
  \begin{subfigure}[lb]{\fluxfigwidth}
  \caption{\the\fluxfigwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{tiger}
  \end{subfigure}
&
  \begin{subfigure}[lb]{\fluxlegwidth}
  \caption{\the\fluxlegwidth}
  \raisebox{0.3\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.4,center]{tiger}}
  \end{subfigure}
\\
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
} % end of \frame
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not a minimal working example because it does not include a complete (but minimal!) preamble and `\begin/\end{document}` tags. Also this is a LaTeX question but you have tagged it as "plain TeX".

Comment: This example still doesn't actually compile.

Comment: never trust myself with latex I guess - forgot subcaption. Please substitute tiger.eps with an eps of your choice.

Comment: Also, I just moved subcaptions above figures to be visible with tiger.eps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each cell within a `tabular` forms a group, so setting a length inside a cell doesn't last beyond that group. Define *and* set the lengths *outside* the `tabular`.

If you're interested in setting two figures next to one another, there's no need to use a `subfigure`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{testing}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    &
    \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-b} \\
    Caption A & Caption B
  \end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Each table cell is a group, therefore your assignments can't make it over the `&`. I'm not sure what you're after, but using `\global\fluxfigwidth=0.5\textwidth` should do the trick.